# what is good way to share constants between node and angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Added at 15 Jan.

What i was worrying is to synchronize protocol values.
below is an API example.

> GET /user/:type
>   type: 'admin' | 'guest' | 'operator'

as much as program get larger, those definitions get larger and more complex and it would be scattered in many places, so adding or changing something take more time.

what I can easily think to solve this problem is use json file.
at the first time each client or server begins, parsing those protocol.json files.
is it only way to solve it?

I hope you to understand what i'm wondering.
how to handle easily large and scattered definition in server and client each side.

---

I wanna share some enumerate values between client(Angular 6) and server(Node.js).

I have to synchronize some values while communicate client and server.

let me give a example.

```
// ProductType in Angular
export enum ProductType {
  phone,
  tablet,
  laptop
}

// ProductType in node.js
const ProductType = module.exports.ProductType = {
  phone: 0,
  tablet: 1,
  laptop: 2
}
```

as you know, it works properly, but I don't think this is good way, because it's getting difficult to manipulate as project is getting bigger and more complex.

what I want to do is share constants between client and server while transferring data.
It doesn't need to be number type, string type is ok.

Comment: What's the difficulty? Data is data. You will need to express it as plain object any way to pass as JSON. Why can't it be written as such inside a module - or several modules?

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do - can you clarify? Also, I believe this is more of a typescript question than Angular-specific.

Comment: @theMayer I added more information in the main text, thank you for your concern in advance.